# Changing set contents using JS on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change a set contents on my website and couldn't get the script working, could someone help.
The contents let say are 4 in numbers and have the following code. i would like to switch between these contents using buttons say 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I am aware that a simple addClass and removeClass will do the trick but couldn't get it working. Here is a sample set of contents:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="article-list-vertical-1">
    <a href="#" style="background-image: url('/img.jpg')"></a>
    <div>
      <h2>Article title #1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eu lacus mattis laoreet diam a volutpat magna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eu lacus mattis laoreet diam a, volutpat magna.</p>
      <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see any script. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is this you're looking for...

https://plnkr.co/edit/BAxRkGJORf2tMt1LFrxK?p=preview

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
   $("#list-1").fadeIn();
   $("#list-2").hide();
   $("#list-3").hide();
   $("#list-4").hide();
});
```

Use the fadeIn() to show the hidden article and hide() to hide the others. There are other way using the tabs by Bootstrap

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tabs.php

Comment: Thank you Leo, for the post that is close enough. I think i have got what i needed within those links. Thanks again cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to:

- include items 2-4 on the page
- hide the appropriate items (css display:none)
- on click of the "read more" link show the next item.

Comment: @DanielRuf What link?

Comment: Sorry, took the wrong flag. The quality of this answer is very ppor and does not really answer the question or provide a solution. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.
Added click event on your anchors, then checked which one was clicked to determine which article to show based on the anchor.

```
  $(".article-link").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var whichLink = $( this ).index()+1;

if( currentArticle != whichLink){

    $('.article-list-vertical-1').each(function(){

      if($( this ).css('display') == 'block'){

        $( this ).animate({opacity:0},function(){
          $( this ).css({"display":"none"});


          $('#list-'+whichLink).css({"display":"block",opacity:0});
          $('#list-'+whichLink).animate({opacity:1},function(){
            currentArticle = whichLink;
          });

        })
      }
    });
}
```

});

With this option, you can easily add more Articles without having to change the "click" handler.

working here: https://plnkr.co/edit/SotgGJVFgR9QtsFBHrSS?p=preview

-cheers mate.

Comment: Any suggestions if i would be adding .article-list-vertical-2 along with article-list-vertical-1 to the script. Cheers!